# Bootcamp Windows does not wake from sleep

Tags: bootcamp, windows, sleep-wake

I'm on a late-2016 MacBook Pro with Touch bar. I recently created Windows partition with Boot Camp which is running a clean install of Windows 10.

When I tell Windows to go to sleep, it will do so. However, it doesn't seem possible to wake it from sleep. While the screen backlight lights up, it remains black and blank, whatever input is given.

The only way to get a functioning environment to return is to hard restart the computer holding down the power button.

I have gone to Device Manager to check whether the keyboard, mouse, etc. are all set to wake the computer from sleep. They are.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I can't in good conscience provide any feedback to this (now three year old) answer. I don't have the specific Windows install _or_ the hardware on which it was installed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really like to post this as a comment because it isn't really an answer - but I don't have the available rep.

I'm having the exact same issue (in terms of failing to wake from sleep). I'm here from Google - on a Mid 15 rMBP. It happens on both Windows and a Linux distribution (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but not on macOS. I am having a similar symptom. That is: the haptic feedback on the touchpad remains active. The device never wakes up, either on a keystroke, clicking the touchpad or pressing the power button.

**I have attempted to reset both the SMC and PRAM to no avail. May I suggest attempting that and seeing how you go?**

The only potential explanation I have come across is that the symptoms developed after I installed an OWC Aura aftermarket SSD. That said, I was not using boot camp immediately prior to installing the OWC SSD. I contacted OWC's support and they have had no reports. Do you by any chance use one of these? I haven't had the time to switch back to my OEM SSD.

Comment: Update nearly two years later! I remembered this post and thought I'd come back in case someone came here through Google. It was absolutely an SSD problem. I ended up submitting an RMA to OWC and had a replacement SSD shipped. With the new SSD installed, the Mac now wakes from sleep as expected using Windows or Linux. I hope this helps someone!

Comment: I got a new Mac mini last month and have the same issues. There is no non-Apple parts in the machine. It has some upgraded parts like i7, 16gb memory, a bigger SSD. I cannot for the life of me wake it up if it falls asleep during boot camp Windows 10. What's more, if I shut down the computer normally from windows 10, it behaves the same, I cannot fully reboot it, even if cutting power between. The only way I'm able to salvage the situation is to hold alt-command-p-r right after turning it on from off state, it *seems* to fix it, and then it'll start in macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a command called [Powercfg](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options) that can modify how devices control the sleep state. First, query the list of devices that support awaking your system:

```
powercfg /devicequery wake_programmable
```

Pay attention to all the devices including the word "keyboard" in their name.
Finally, use the option `/deviceenablewake "<device_name>"` to enable the device that should wake your system from sleep. For example:

```
powercfg /deviceenablewake "HID Keyboard Device"
```

Comment: Even running terminal as admin, I get "You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake.".

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I do see the same problem on all Mac hardware when I use bootcamp+windows. I tried to call Apple support, but all I get from them is that it's a windows issue (and I've never seen anything like that in windows). I'm absolutely positively sure that it's an apple bug/issue.
The problem I have is that after my 2019 mac mini goes to sleep I absolutely cannot turn on my screen. Screen shows "no signal" message. I tried to unplug hdmi cable, plug it back in: nothing helps, hardware stays in off state completely. The only solution is a hard reset. Also, I've seen where usb devices do not wake up after computer goes to sleep mode: usually, in that case my keyboard is not responding to any keystrokes as if computer is off, pressing CapsLock doesn't change led indicator etc. But if I unplug it from usb port and plug it back in, then it works.

So far, what I see, is that mac hardware somehow does not properly turn it on devices, even though the OS actually does make the request to wake it up. Here's how you can check: when your computer (I assume it's in Windows/bootcamp) is asleep, try to remotely login into it. It's not going to work (unless you have wake-on-lan or something like that, but let's assume that you don't have wake-on-lan). Now, try to press space bar to wake up your pc and even if it still appears to be asleep, it's actually isn't asleep: you'll be able to remotely login into it and use it as if it's not asleep. Except, there is some hardware issue with macs/bootcamp that actual hardware isn't switched to powered state.

I have macbook pro 15/16 multiple models, and I have mac mini 2019 and with all of them I saw that issue happening from time to time, but with my mac mini it's so severe that I have no choice but to configure windows to prevent it from going into sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this on a Dell Precision M3800.

running powercfg /devicequery wake_programmable returned lots of ambiguous device names, including lots of USB Hubs (the system internals contain two plus I was an external USB-C hub for desktop monitors etc.) but no matter what I did with an external wired keyboard+wireless Mouse or wireless keyboard/Mouse combo they wouldn't show up in Powercfg.

The only devices wake_armed were

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260    
Dell GigabitEthernet
```

None of the HID devices in Device Manager had a power management tab.

To fix it, I did a full shutdown on Windows 10, CMD/Admin prompt via

```
shutdown /s/r
```

Then I went into Bios setup via F2 on startup before Windows 10 loaded.

In Bios setup there was a USB Wake Support option, it was disabled. Enabled it, save config and exit.

When Windows booted everything was fixed. The HID devices in Device Manager had Power Management tabs, and showed up powercfg

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /devicequery wake_programmable
Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
HID-compliant vendor-defined device
HID-compliant mouse
HID-compliant touch screen
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (005)
HID-compliant consumer control device (004)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (007)
HID Keyboard Device (005)
Dell GigabitEthernet
HID-compliant system controller (003)
HID-compliant system controller (004)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (015)
HID Keyboard Device (007)
HID-compliant consumer control device (015)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (018)
HID-compliant mouse (008)
```

Also, now the devices in device manager including the keyboard and mouse had Power Management tabs, and Allow device to wake computer was already set on.

[image: Picture of device manager power mgmt tab]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know I am late but I think I know the answer. It is because even though your MacBook screen is black after sleep, it's because the screen brightness is off. Sometimes for some reason, the brightness gets set to the lowest and nothing shows on the screen because the brightness is off. So, when that happens, just press the brightness button and make your screen brighter. Then, you should see the screen.

I don't know if this is a bug, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the other answers got me thinking, windows have a sleep hard disk option in power settings. It is possible that functionality doesn't play well with the SSD in Macbook Pros.

I made this change in the Power Options -> Advanced Settings to set turn off hard disk to 'never' and the issue is solved on my 2015-MBP.

[image]